# What is the probability for which :$\gcd ((\phi(n),n-1)=1 ) $ for integers?

Tags: probability, totient-function, coprime

let $n$ be an integer and $\phi$ is The Euler's Totient function.

I want to know the probability for which $$\gcd ((\phi(n),n-1)=1 ) $$

I only know if $n$ is a prime number then the probability is 0 because we have $\phi(p)=p-1$ then $$\gcd(\phi(p),p-1) =p-1=\phi(p)$$ , then my question is :What is the probability for which :$$\gcd ((\phi(n),n-1)=1 ) $$ for integers   ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an unsolved problem. For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem

Comment: According to the wikipedia article there is no known composite $n$ s.t. $\phi(n)$ divides $n-1$, but is that the same thing as gcd = 1?  (I am not an expert on $\phi$ at all.)  Anyway, if they are the same thing, then the wiki article includes a bound s.t you know for any $x$ how many $n \le x$ can have gcd $\neq 1$ (i.e. $n$ prime, or $n$ is one of these never-seen-before composites), and then depending on your choice of probabilities (over all integers) you can bound Prob(gcd = 1).

Comment: @user112358 , Your answer is talking about primality test of Lehmer conjecture , but I asked about the probability for which  phi(n) not divides n-1